# Ecommerce Payment Gateway that allows commission to be taken

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am currently writing a PHP application. Unfortunately due to budget, we cannot be PCI compliant.

The application is basically just a marketplace where we take money from a user, take a small commission, and when the action is completed and confirmed, we give the money to the user who completed this action.

I have tried using Braintree, WePay, Stripe, etc. but nothing seems to fit what I am trying to do. The workflow is theoretically simple, however doesn't seem to be easy to implement.

With Braintree it seemed to be possible, but the main blocker was that the business models didn't match, so we weren't able to get a live license. With WePay, we require being PCI compliant, which is not feasible for us.

Was just looking for some guidance if possible.

**Note: The language we are programming in is PHP, so the API of the payment gateway must be compatible with PHP.**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for that John. DIdn't know that. I'll fix that up asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WePay doesn't require you to be PCI compliant.  If you use their [embedded checkout](https://developer.wepay.com/docs/process-payments/embedded-checkout) you take on none of the PCI compliance, but you sacrifice access to any of the card details, but that's only problematic if you want to offer recurring transactions.  For most situations, their iframe should work just fine.

WePay's [tokenization solution](https://developer.wepay.com/docs/process-payments/custom-checkout) also doesn't require a lot of PCI compliance.  I believe they ask that their partners complete SAQ-A-EP.  Which is a simple self-assessment questionnaire that you only have to do once a year.

Comment: That is true, but the front end of the application is an iOS app. That would imply needing to use webviews for the iframe loading, am I correct?

Comment: True.  Let me update my answer to include some more details.